# How to stop the line breaking in css when zooming in and out on page?

Tags: css, zooming, line-breaks

When i zoom in/out the page the text seem to break ,it separates in another line. The first quick link is ok , but there seems to be a problem with the second and third quick links and lorem text. I am sorry that i am posting picture but stackoverlow doen't allow me to post the code. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY5Vw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the element containing the text. `white-space: nowrap;`